# Select the first option by value when there are duplicate values

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have a `select` list that contains duplicate values. I don't have the power to change this.

```
<select id="dropdown">
    <option value="1">Item 1</option>
    <option value="1">Item 1 again under a different name</option>
    <option value="2">Item 2</option>
</select>
```

In a different place, I have a link element that, when clicked, calls `$("#dropdown").val(1)`. This "Item 1 again under a different name" to be selected and displayed. I want "Item 1" to be selected instead. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that you can select the `option` element by the `value` attribute and use the `:first` selector. Try this:

```js
var value = 1;
$('#dropdown option[value="' + value + '"]:first').prop('selected', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dropdown">
  <option>Please select...</option>
  <option value="1">Item 1</option>
  <option value="1">Item 1 again under a different name</option>
  <option value="2">Item 2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
 $("#dropdown option[value=1]:first").prop({selected:true});
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess there will be only one duplicate value in dropdown. First you need to find that value than select first option of same value.

```
var arrDuplicate = [];
var duplicateVal = 0;
$("#dropdown option").each(function () {
if (arrDuplicate.indexOf($(this).val()) > -1)
  duplicateVal = $(this).val();
arrDuplicate.push($(this).val());
});

$("#dropdown option[value=" + duplicateVal + "]:first").attr("selected", "selected");
```